# Will every single line of JavaScript need to be interpreted before the first line is executed?

Tags: javascript

I tend to think of JavaScript like Ruby, that the first line is interpreted and executed, and the last line won't be interpreted until the very end.

But since JavaScript is subject to the hoisting rule, such as:

```
console.log(foo);   // foo already has a value

function foo() {
    return 123;
}
```

so what if the `console.log` is the first line of the JavaScript file linked from the HTML, and the file is 200kb, and then the HTML file links 10 other JavaScript files, and the `foo` is defined at the last line of the last file, then since by the hoisting rule, the `foo` needs to be defined even at the first line, so that means all 11 files have to be downloaded ***and interpreted*** before even the first line can get executed?

Answer (score 0):

No. Browsers deal with one file (or rather, script element) at a time. Later script elements will be added to the same environment (thus sharing variables) but won't be waited for.

If the first file you load calls a function that isn't defined until the second file is read then it will error. (Unless that call comes from a function which isn't called until after the second file has been loaded).

Comment: Before, I thought that linking one big file that is concatenated together is the same as linking 10 files separately, so there is this one subtle difference?  So if some framework such as Ruby on Rails concat all 11 files into one file and link it, then that one big file will need to be interpreted for every line before the first line can be executed?

Comment: Yes, but that difference is only going to cause problems if functions are redefined (which is an edge case you should be avoiding anyway). Interpreting a JS file is a cheap operation, much, much cheaper then making 10 additional HTTP requests.

Comment: even with the HTTP `Keep-alive`?  Especially if the files are all cached in RAM and there is no disk IO

Comment: Even with keep-alive. Files won't be cached on the initial load.